# Any drupal 7 view for creating rss feed format like http://www.campaignmonitor.com/create/rss-to-email/#data-repeater

Tags: xml, rss, drupal-7, drupal-views

Is anybody know how to create xml format like http://www.campaignmonitor.com/create/rss-to-email/#data-repeater in drupal 7. What I need is, output a xml with custom node and custom attributes.
The format is like

```
<h3>The latest from our blog</h3>
<datarepeater type="rss" src="http://abcwidgets.com">
    <h4><rsstitle tocitem></h4>
    <p>Posted by <rssauthor /> on <rssitemday />/<rssitemmonth /></p>
    <rssimage width="600" />
    <rssbody paragraphs="all" />
</datarepeater>
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, drupal questions go to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Another thing is that you can do in various ways. It would be helpful if you would tell what exactly you are trying to do and why.
Drupal has "views" where you can export XML that you want. This is probably the best way to look for your solution.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have an content type event. The above mentioned url (http://www.campaignmonitor.com ) is an application to send update(newsletter) to emails(we can set in app) from given xml feed. That xml feed have predefined nodes and attributes. And I need to create an xml for that.